# Accord.Net Get equation of the SVM model

Tags: c#, machine-learning, accord.net

I have been testing the sample Kernel Support Vector Machines for regression problems and I would like to know how do you get the equation of the model.

For example, if the machine is created using a polynomial kernel (degree = 1), how do you get the line equation (mx + b) of this model. Is there any method in the SupportVectorMachine Class to get the model equation? or is there any way to calculate the parameters of the equation from the variables obtained after the machine is created.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can use this method below:

[`ToWeights()`](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_MachineLearning_VectorMachines_SupportVectorMachine_2_ToWeights.htm), which

> Converts a Linear-kernel machine into an array of linear coefficients.
>   The first position in the array is the Threshold value.

So in your language, the first position in the array is the bias `b` and the rest are your linear coefficients `m`.

Comment: I dont understand the answer.
For a line, y=x, the output array is {0,4,0},
For a line, y = 2x, the output array is {0,7,0}.
I just added this line 
double[] linearCoef = svm.ToWeights();

Comment: Did you provide enough training data? How did you learn your model? What is your training data? Please be specific.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. I am using a simple demo of 6 data pairs. For y=x {(0,0), (1,1),...,(5,5)} and for y=2x  {(0,0),(1,2),...,(5,10)} . I am using the demo sample "Kernel Support Vector Machines for regression problems" and I create machine using a polynomial kernel degree =1, constant =1. The graphical output shown the model is what do I expect (a line passing through all the data points) with error =0

Comment: If you have a problem of 2 variables, let's say ```x``` and ```y```, shouldn't you be expecting the formula to be something like ```z = xa + yb + c``` instead of ```y = mx```? In this case, if the framework is giving as output an array {0, 4, 0}, it means ```c = 0``` (the first is the threshold/bias) and then that ```a = 4``` and ```b = 0```.

Answer (score 2):

I got weird coefficients from ToWeights() when using SequentialMinimalOptimization() from which I couldn't derive the hyperplane equation. Using LinearCoordinateDescent() yielded usable coefficients for the model, however, in the form of [a,b,c...] which could be plugged in as 0 = a + bx + cy + ...
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As @zrolfs noted, if you are using Accord.NET with Sequential Minimal Optimization, the ToWeights() function does not currently return relevant coefficients for the decision function. Nevertheless, you can calculate these coefficients directly. In order to do so, multiply the SVM weights vector by the matrix of support vectors, like so:

```
double[] DecisionFunctionCoefficients = new double[dwTotalFeatures];
for (int iFeature = 0; iFeature < dwTotalFeatures; iFeature++) {
     for (int iVector = 0; iVector < SVM.SupportVectors.Length; iVector++) {
         DecisionFunctionCoefficients[iFeature] += (SVM.SupportVectors[iVector][iFeature] * SVM.Weights[iVector]);
     }
}
```